# ¿Cómo agrupar cuando tengo un case con fecha?

Tags: sql, group-by

Quiero agrupar un case que se ve algo asi:

```
Select d.cuentaid,case when d.fecha between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-30' then SUM(d.valor) else 0 END AS 'DEP-ENE',
case when d.fecha between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-29' then SUM(d.valor) else 0 END AS 'DEP-FEB'
FROM deposito as d 
GROUP by d.fecha, d.cuentaid
```

Sin embargo, sigue sin agruparse por el "cuentaid", el resultado sigue saliendo por cada deposito y no agrupado por cuentaid, lo agrupe tambien por la fecha porque el sql me lo pedia.

Asi me sigue saliendo:

```
023-303-593723  137135  0
023-303-593723  3000    0
023-303-593723  2500    0
023-303-593723  12757   0
023-303-593723  12055   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que poner la función de agregado afuera del CASE.

```
SELECT d.cuentaid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-30' THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'DEP-ENE',
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.fecha BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29' THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'DEP-FEB'
FROM deposito as d 
GROUP BY d.cuentaid;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, fuiste de mucha ayuda.